# How to have several models in one - Prisma

Tags: prisma

Currenty I am going to try define multiple models with the same name but I have a warning when I define Two models with same name:

For example: This is my file "parameters.prisma"

```js
// ◮◮◮ GENERATED BY AURORA ◮◮◮
datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model Reminder {
  id          String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title       String
  description String?
  codeClass   String?
  userId      String?
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime? @updatedAt

  @@map("Parameters")
}

model ActivityType {
  id          String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title       String
  description String?
  codeClass   String?
  userId      String?
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime? @updatedAt

  @@map("Parameters")
}
```

The part: '@@map("Parameters")' changes the name of models Reminder and ActivityType. I need to put those models as a model named Parameters. In my MongoDB, I need to have a only model named Parameters that have data of Reminder and ActivityType models. Its fields of both models will change in a future. Its only an example in this time.

Well. How I can do this part?. Prisma show me this error: [image: prisma-error] Or exists other best way for do this part?

Comment: Two collections can not have the same name. Do you want to store the models Reminder and ActivityType as sub-documents in the Parameter model?

Comment: Hi @NurulSundarani after talking about it. The conclusion was reached that there should be a single module, also thanks for responding. This is no longer a problem

Comment: I am glad to hear that this was resolved.